# Refactor using loop query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to refactor a loop query in rails in the below code:

```
users.each do |user|
  books+=(book.where(user_id: user))
end
```

I found that, here I can use group_by or index. But could not understand how to do that?

Can someone please help me out with that.

Comment: I don’t really understand what you’re doing here. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AJFaraday in the above query, I have used loop. I want it to refactor by using group_by or index_by. How can I do that?

Comment: and what is the purpose of the refactor? What are you doing with it after that loop?

Comment: @AJFaraday To make the code small. I using books to find the authors.

Comment: Perhaps I’m not being clear. Why do you want the code to do? What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want all the books that belong to any of the users in your users array/relation.

Assuming you have a proper `belongs_to :user` in your `Book` model, the following query will do what you need. No group_by needed.

```
Book.where(user: users)
```

An index in the database will still make it faster and as a rule of thumb all foreign keys should be indexed (exceptions exist of course)

Comment: Thank you, but can you also please tell how can I use this with `group_by` and `index_by`, so that I can use them in future.

Comment: Also by doing this `Book.where(user: users)` will it be added to the *array* of books?